# Is Javascript/AJAX still supported in ArcGIS 10?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

A colleague of mine claims that the ArcGIS Javascript web API is not supported for ArcGIS 10+.  I searched their website but all the information seemed to indicate that it should still work.

Any insights?

Comment: Perhaps your colleague was confusing the Javascript API with the [Java web ADF](http://events.esri.com/uc/QandA/index.cfm?fuseaction=answer&conferenceId=2F6DC1A1-1422-2418-883C3868A9004888&questionId=3060), which will not be supported in future versions.

Comment: yeah your colleague is definitely confused.  I think the javascript is the strongest of the web api's and will continue to be so with the adoption of HTML5 while silverlight and flex battle it out for esri's attention.

Comment: Agreed with above, Javascript API should be around for awhile.  Dot Net and Java should start to fade, while in my opinion Silverlight and Flex will decline in use as well.  Much of programming is moving towards open source and standards based, and Javascript is the only option right now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have heard of the web ADFs for .NET and Java being deprecated at 10.1 but I haven't heard of the Javascript API being discontinued.

If there was a plan to do so it would be listed here in the  [ESRI deprecation plan document](http://downloads2.esri.com/support/TechArticles/ArcGIS10and101Deprecation_Plan.pdf)

Answer (score 7):

ArcGIS JavaScript API is definitely supported in ArcGIS Server 10.  Here's the [API Docs](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/)

Answer (score 3):

With ArcGIS, we now have the REST API so any JavaScript API can be used even if Esri were to cancel the JavaScript API.

That said they just [updated it a couple weeks](http://www.spatiallyadjusted.com/2011/03/03/esri-releases-arcgis-api-for-javascript-2-2/) ago so I wouldn't worry too much about it.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript API is the future and their new product ArcGIS Online is completely built on Javascript API.